# Lutron Maestro and companions

Tags: light, dimmer-switch

I have 3 light switches in the hallway controlling one light (a 4-way (USA) switch set up). I installed a Lutron Maestro switch on position one (has red, black, green and white wire) and the companion on position 3 and both switches are working.

The middle switch has 2 red and 2 black wires and a green one (4 way switch). I don't know how to connect these wires to the companion. I feel I need to go back to regular switches, not dimmers.

Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I tried to clean up the question a bit an added some formatting to make it easier to read. Please double check to be sure I've interpreted the situation correctly, or edit again to clarify. Additionally, you said "pictures" (plural), but only included one, very small picture. Did you mean to include others? Could you possibly repost the existing pic so that it's bigger - it's really hard to see what's going on in that tiny picture.

Comment: We'll need the model numbers of your Maestro devices to tell you for sure. Also, it would be helpful to have pictures of the existing switches in each box from all sides so we can see which terminals which wires are connected to. In general though, I remember having to basically pigtail a couple of wires in the "middle" position boxes when installing Maestro dimmers with more than 2 locations.

Comment: Apparently Maestros are simultaneously 3- and 4-way. You **double tap the blue screw on the middle one** and that makes it a '4-way'.

Answer (score 1):

I'm answering based off using the Maestro MACL-153M switch and its proper companions.

I just recently did this to some switches in my house. I found this YouTube video (https://youtu.be/EGyXhV0p-4w) to help me figure out which wire is hot, load, and travelers.

It will be helpful if you have a line load detector as described in the video and a multimeter. You can also get away with just a multimeter if you don't have a line load detector. Assuming you turned the breaker off to disconnect the switch, turn the power back on. Turn your meter to VAC and start at a switch that only has 3 colored wires. Now touch 1 lead to 1 of the wires and the other lead to another wire. If no volts detected, leave 1 lead on a wire and touch the other lead to the other wire. If no voltage is detected, this pair should be your travelers. To make sure, now test the final combination of wires you haven't already tested. If you still don't see any voltage, you're probably at the load end of the switches and repeat the process at the other location with only 3 colored wires.

I'll describe switch locations as positions 1, 2, and 3, where position 1 is the switch has the incoming hot wire, position 2 is the 4 way where its only connections are the traveler wires coming from positions 1 and 3, and 3 is the switch that has the wire that goes to the load (presumably lights, or could be fan, etc.).

My wiring has 3 colored wires and bare copper (ground) wire. In my case, position 1 has 1 black hot lead, 1 red and 1 black traveler. Position 2 has 2 each of red and black traveler wires. Position 3 has 1 black load wire, 1 red and black traveler wires. For each of the switches I connected the ground wire to its green ground screws.

First, I followed the instructions in the YouTube video to find the hot, load, and traveler wires. Then I started by connecting the dimmer switch as position 1 and the 2 companion switches at positions 2 and 3. Using the Lutron installation guide (https://www.lutron.com/TechnicalDocumentLibrary/369613a.pdf) or see diagram below.

I started at position 1 and connected the hot lead to the dimmer's common (black) screw and travelers to brass and blue in no particular order. Then, I did position 3 next. I mimicked the connections here that I made for position 1 where the load wire goes to the common (black) screw and connected the other 2 wires in the same way I did at position 1. At position 3 I paired the wires by color and connected the  2 traveler lines by color at the 4 way switch. Pretty much just followed the instructions provided by Lutron (see picture below) which can be found at . You can also use the Lutron's interactive installation helper tool at webtools.lutron.com.

[image]